# 1D linear spin-chain for Ising model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, interactions, ising-model

In section 2.1 of the article https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07112 appears the following Hamiltonian for a 1D chain of $n$-spins

$$
H = \sum_{i = 1}^n \sigma^x_i\sigma^x_{i + 1} + \sigma^y_1\sigma^z_2···\sigma^z_{n - 1}\sigma^y_n + \lambda\sum_{i = 1}^n\sigma^z_i
$$

and it is said that the second term is to cancel the periodic boundary term $\sigma^x_n\sigma^x_1$. Nonetheless, I don't see how that term cancels $\sigma^x_n\sigma^x_1$ since all $\sigma$s in $\sigma^y_1\sigma^z_2···\sigma^z_{n - 1}\sigma^y_n$ commutes for being operators that acts on different particles of the chain. Therefore, there are no anticommutation rules that could lead you to any $\sigma^x$

Comment: the key phrase is "cancel the periodic boundary term, $\sigma^x_n\sigma^x_1$, **after the Jordan-Wigner transformation**". When you plug in the transformation given in Eq. 4 you can see how this translates to the terms the appears in Eq. 5. More specifically, the $\sigma^y_1$ and $\sigma^y_n$ that appear in the second term do have non-trivial commutation relations with $\sigma^x_{1,n}$.

Comment: @yu-v Could you work it up a little bit more? Thanks

Comment: Just note that combining the chain of $\sigma^z$ in Eq.(4) with the fact that $\sigma^y_1 = -i\sigma^x_1\sigma^z_1$ you can substitute the second term to be a quadratic combination of $c^{\dagger}_1$, $c_1$, $c^{\dagger}_n$, and $c_n$. Follow the substitution rules for the first term as combine them. What exactly do you find difficulty with?